# VLC and Cover art problem

Tags: vlc

For some reason the cover artwork for many of my songs has stopped or is incorrect. Is there anyway to reset Vlc so I can get the cover art to show or display the right cover? I have tried add cover art from file but that doesn't pop out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily reset vlc setting by renaming your vlc configuration folder. Open terminal by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command (bak stand for backup):

```
mv ~/.config/vlc ~/.config/vlc.bak
```

After you execute those command, vlc will act like its original state.

Comment: Didn't work. I tried uninstall  and reinstalling it that didn't work either

Comment: never mind it worked it just took a bit of time

Answer (score -1):

You can try deleting the `~/.cache/Vlc` file. You can use the `rm` command for doing the same:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/Vlc
```

It's working!